# Issue Incrementing a Value Inside an ActionListener

Tags: java, properties, conditional-statements, actionlistener

I'm trying to increment/decrement a user score as appropriate inside a text field on a (very) basic GUI. How, I only succeed in decrementing even though there is proof my conditional works correctly. Here is the pertinent code; I can supply more as needed.

```
//buttons: array of JButtons
//scoretxt: JTextField holding the score
//name- object name stored as string in separate string array
//check- odd numbers pass incorrect, evens pass correct
//safe: JTextArea for output

for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    final String myname = "" + (buttons[i].getClientProperty("name"));
    final String myval = "" + (buttons[i].getClientProperty("value"));
    final String corr = "" + (buttons[i].getClientProperty("check"));
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            safe.append(myname + " " + ("" + myval));
            if (corr == "correct") {
                safe.append(" " + corr + "\n");
                scoretxt.setText("" + ((Integer.parseInt(scoretxt.
                        getText())) + 1));
            } else {
                safe.append(" " + corr + "\n");
                scoretxt.setText("" + ((Integer.parseInt(scoretxt.
                        getText())) - 1));
            }
        }
    });

    mygui.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

I have tried various approaches but I always rely on `scoretxt.getText()` to pass a value. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this probably won't help, but just to clean up the code, have you tried saving getText() to a variable? e.g. int score = Integer.parseInt(scoretxt.getText())

Comment: yes, i have- final int mytemp = Integer.parseInt(scoretxt.getText()); for one version

Comment: @Antidiscrete, Did you check if the condition `corr=="correct"` gets true and goes inside `if` block where increment happens ?

Comment: On top of what Ravi said. It should be corr.equals("correct"). Never do a comparison with Strings with ==

Comment: @JohnathanAu, you are right. String comparison does not work like that. good catch. That is the problem. Antidiscrete needs to use string.equal method.

Comment: @Ravi Trivedi I have and to confirm the condition is met the output looks like this: onelft 5 - correct onergt 9 - incorrect(format is "name" value" "corr")

Comment: @Antidiscrete, how you are comparing strings is wrong. You need to use string.equals method. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Lol, the .equals change actually solved it. Boy do I feel stupid. +1 to all of you for a quick and effective solution, thank you.

Comment: We all make stupid mistakes, cheers ! :)

Comment: Don't worry. Everyone makes silly mistakes when programming!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `equals()` method to compare two strings.

```
corr.equals("correct");
```

Please refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?rq=1)